# Relevanssi won't show all results on my website

Tags: wordpress, search, relevanssi

I'm having an issue with the search results on my WordPress website. I'm using the Avada Theme.

I'm using Relevanssi as a search plugin, but it is not working correctly. When I search for a certain term, it gives me some related results, but it also gives me random results.

The example I want to use is: I search for "CRN" and it gives me correct results that include the term "CRN". However, it'll miss "CRN2" in the results and add a bunch of random results. If I look for "CRN2" it leaves out "CRN".

I also noticed that when I look at the portfolio tab in my dashboard, the same thing happens. This makes me think that maybe it isn't relevanssi if it's happening in the backend also.

Any insight on this is greatly appreciated. I will attach some screenshots as reference[image: CRN search]

[image: CRN 2 search]
[image: dashboard portfolio search]

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the [Relevanssi supoort team](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/relevanssi/) about this yet? If not it might be a good idea to do so, if anyone knows why that's happening on your site it would be them.

Comment: I didn't think about it, to be honest, but I might! I find the whole back end results and the front end results being the same very strange. I've never seen that before

Comment: Have you looked at the Relevanssi settings page Indexing tab?  (Settings -> Relevanssi -> Indexing).  That tab invites you to choose which post types to index.  You might also try fiddling with the "Keyword Matching" item on the Searching tab to see if you get better results.  And, do ask Mikko and his team for help.